# StepFunction timing out after invoking from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda function and a step function. I am trying to invoke my step function from my Lambda function. To do this, I did the following: (1) Provide my Lambda a role of 'AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess', (2) Made sure to pass in the correct input format for my step function (the only parameter it has is a `$.Payload`)

My code to invoke my step function looks like:

```
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
transactionId = str(uuid.uuid1());

my_dict =... #This is the input I want to provide
input = {'Payload': {'input1': "HELLO"}} //Ideally I want to pass in a dict to my 

response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:us-west-2:ACCOUNTNumber:stateMachine:MyStateMachineTest',
    name=transactionId,
    input= json.dumps(input)
)
```

For some reason, I keep getting the following error in my logs: `2023-02-08T08:05:51.888Z 948af460-9ca2-4d42-aea5-6b26ba007ceb Task timed out after 3.07 seconds`

I tried so many things but still can not figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add some logging to your lambda to see where it is stuck. Is it in a VPC? Increase the timeout to 15 minutes and see if anything else comes up.

Comment: So I haven't created any VPC. My lambda isn't in any VPC and neither is my Step Function. It's all serverless, so I haven't even gone into the VPC menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is most probably because you have set a timeout to your lambda function (the one invoking the state machine). If you go to your `Lambda function -> General Configuration -> Edit -> Timeout (increase this value)`. Try doing that and it should start working.